# C++ How to get Windows icon from GUID?

Tags: c++, windows, icons, guid, windows-shell

How can I get an icon associated with a shell GUID in C++?

like this: {B2C761C6-29BC-4f19-9251-E6195265BAF1}

this guid is for color management shortcut and I want to get the icon for it, is there an API function which can do this ?

Comment: How did you get that GUID? It should have come out of the shell namespace, in which case you use the same namespace to get the icon.